# Minimum value of maximum values of two dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays

okay i have another question because as i told you i am trying to put all these values in result 3 as i mentioned before like this ( x , y ) then i have to get the max value of each point of this ( x , y ) for the whole points then get the min value of the maximum values , i managed to get the maximum values but when i try to get the minimum of them it turns shows zero.

This is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
                        {


                            result3[i, j] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                            Console.WriteLine(result3[i, j]);
                            if (result1[i, j] > result2[k, m])
                            {
                                highestMoment[i, j] = result1[i, j];

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                highestMoment[i, j] = result2[k, m];
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(highestMoment[i, j]);

                            if (lowestMoment[i, j] > highestMoment[i, j])
                            {
                                lowestMoment[i, j] = highestMoment[i, j];
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(lowestMoment[i, j]);

                            counter++;



                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

and this the whole code

```
double[,] Cranelocations = { { -12.3256, 0.5344 }, { -12.3256, -0.4656 }, { -12.3256, -1.4656 }, { -12.3256, -2.4656 } };
 double[,] Picklocation = { { -0.3256, -3.4656 }, { 0.6744, -3.4656 }, { 1.6744, -3.4656 }, { 2.6744, -3.4656 }, { 3.6744, -3.4656 }, { 4.6744, -3.4656 }, { 5.6744, -3.4656 } };
double[,] Setlocation = { { 20.62, 5.03 }, { 24.28, 5.03 }, { 28.40, 5.03 }, { 32.11, 5.03 }, { 35.99, 5.26 }, { 40.18, 5.26 } };
double[] Weights = { 11.7865, 14.7335, 15.1015, 10.7465 };
double[,] result1 = new double[Weights.Length * Cranelocations.GetLength(0), Picklocation.GetLength(0)];
    double[,] result2 = new double[Weights.Length * Cranelocations.GetLength(0), Setlocation.GetLength(0)];
    object[,] result3 = new object[result1.GetLength(0), result1.GetLength(1)];
    double[,] highestMoment = new double[result3.GetLength(0), result3.GetLength(1)];
    double[,] lowestMoment = new double[highestMoment.GetLength(0), highestMoment.GetLength(1)];
    int counter = 0;




                    for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)
                    {
                        int offset = m * Cranelocations.GetLength(0);

                        for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < Picklocation.GetLength(0); j++)
                            {
                                double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Picklocation[j, 0];
                                double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Picklocation[j, 1];

                                result1[i + offset, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");

                    for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Length; m++)

                    {
                        int offset = m * Cranelocations.GetLength(0);

                        for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < Setlocation.GetLength(0); j++)
                            {


                                double x = Cranelocations[i, 0] - Setlocation[j, 0];
                                double y = Cranelocations[i, 1] - Setlocation[j, 1];

                                result2[i +offset, j] = Weights[m] * (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));
                                //Console.WriteLine(result2[i, j]);

                            }

                        }
                    }




                    for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
                            {
                                for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
                                {


                                    result3[i, j] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                                    Console.WriteLine(result3[i, j]);
                                    if (result1[i, j] > result2[k, m])
                                    {
                                        highestMoment[i, j] = result1[i, j];

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        highestMoment[i, j] = result2[k, m];
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine(highestMoment[i, j]);

                                    if (lowestMoment[i, j] > highestMoment[i, j])
                                    {
                                        lowestMoment[i, j] = highestMoment[i, j];
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine(lowestMoment[i, j]);

                                    counter++;







                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Its a nice thought, that if you want us to seriously look at your question, you could spend 1 minute to format it so its readable

Comment: I am sorry but have posted the same code an hour ago for another problem and one of the guys here (thanks to him) replied with the solution and didn't make any comment about how the code looks like so i thought it was readable !!

Comment: @MichaelRandall Also i am a beginner so i am sorry if you find my way of coding is not readable but i am trying to learn..

Comment: A few suggestions to improve your question: Make it self-contained. Nobody will search for your other question. State exactly what you have and what you want. In that line, what minimum of what maximum do you mean? I find it very hard to tell. And I don't see what the code is doing. And **fix the formatting** as you have already been asked. Use the edit button under the question.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for advice, i will follow it for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning `lowestMoment` before comparing it to `highestMoment`. Since the default value of a `double` is 0 then lowestMoment will always be lower than anything you compare it to giving your results of 0.

This might be what you're looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int iOffset = i * result1.GetLength(1);

    for (int j = 0; j < result1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < result2.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            int kOffset = k * result2.GetLength(1);

            for (int m = 0; m < result2.GetLength(1); m++)
            {
                result3[iOffset + j, kOffset + m] = result1[i, j] + "," + result2[k, m];
                Console.WriteLine(result3[iOffset + j, kOffset + m]);

                if (result1[i, j] > result2[k, m])
                {
                    highestMoment[i, j] = result1[i, j];
                }
                else
                {
                    highestMoment[i, j] = result2[k, m];
                }

                if (lowestMoment[i, j] == 0
                    || lowestMoment[i, j] > highestMoment[i, j])
                {
                    lowestMoment[i, j] = highestMoment[i, j];
                }

                Console.WriteLine(highestMoment[i, j]);
                Console.WriteLine(lowestMoment[i, j]);

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's close actually, it's just i want to get the minimum value of the maximum values that i got from result 3, for example i got ( 1, 2) , (5 ,6) , (10, 8) the maximums of each point are (10 , 5 , 2) then i want to get the minimum of this 3 points so it will be ( 2). This number (2) is what i am looking for.

Comment: Ok see my edit. But again, like before, you are overwriting `highestMoment` on every iteration of m & k. You would have to change the indexes to be the same as `result3`. But this answers your question why are the minimum values 0.

Comment: @AlaaMagdy Sorry Visual Studio was updating so I was typing those answers by hand. This should give you what you're looking for I hope.

Comment: it's getting closer but it's not showing the lowest value yet however i really appreciate your help

Comment: The solution before this was the closest one however it gives me the two lowest minimum values and i want only the minimum one.

Comment: Ah, I just got it! You just need to flip around the logic until it does what you want it to ;)